# Splitting string with three delimeters in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, split

String pattern:

```
1#5,7;2#;3#4
```

These are three sets of values separated by semicolon.

Digit before # goes in one column, digits after # (separated by comma) go in another column (so the second set in this case only has one value)

How can I do this?

This is what I found on the net:

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX) = '1,100,12345|2,345,433|3,23423,123|4,33,55'

DECLARE @x xml = '<r><c>' + 
             REPLACE(REPLACE(@S, ',','</c><c>'),'|','</c></r><r><c>') + 
             '</c></r>'

 SELECT x.value('c[1]','int') AS seq,
   x.value('c[2]','int') AS invoice,
   x.value('c[3]','int') AS amount
 FROM @x.nodes('/r') x(x)
```

This however has fixed no. of figures after every delimiter. And it also uses only 2 delimiters.

Comment: Looks like you have 3 _values_ and one primary delimiter (the semicolon).  There's a list of five ways of splitting strings in T-SQL as well as a performance comparison of the methods [here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings).

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I already mentioned that. Digit before # goes in one column (so may be it could be stored in a temporary variable); digit(s) after # go in another column. The same repeats after semicolon.